# How identify a secondary Id of a html element with multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, one of the jsp pages have this html structure:

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-a" class="campos">
  <thead>
  <tr>    
      <th>Campo</th>
      <th>#</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="nome_campo"> </td>
    <td> <button type="button" id="incluir_campo" class="btn btn-link">Incluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <div id="result_incluir_campo"></div> </td>
    <td> <div id="result_excluir_campo"></div> </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <c:forEach var="item_key" items="${campos}">
  <tr id="linha_campo_${item_key}">
    <td> <input type="text" value="${item_key}"> </td>
    <td> <button type="button" id="excluir_campo_${item_key}" class="btn btn-link">Excluir</button> </td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Note the line:

```
<button type="button" id="excluir_campo_${item_key}" class="btn btn-link">Excluir</button>
```

I have one jquery function associated to it:

```
<c:forEach var="item_key" items="${campos}">
<script>
$("#excluir_campo_${item_key}").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/key/remove_campo"/>",
        cache: false,
        data: {nome: "${item_key}"}
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data == "yes") {
            $("#linha_campo_${item_key}").remove();
        }
        else if(data == "not"){
            $("#result_excluir_campo").empty().append("erro");
        }
        else {
            $("#result_excluir_campo").empty().append("sem acesso");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</c:forEach>
```

I was using jstl, but i am facing some problems with this solution, since my list can be updated dynamicly.

Take in consideration I change the Id from this element:

```
<button type="button" id="excluir_campo_${item_key}" class="btn btn-link">Excluir</button>
```

to this two (separating the two "terms" of current Id):

```
excluir_campo ${item_key}
```

is there any way to detect the secong id with a jquery function similar to that:

```
$("#excluir_campo").on("click", function () {
    var second_id = ???;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/key/remove_campo"/>",
        cache: false,
        data: {nome: "<second_id>"}
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data == "yes") {
            $("#linha_campo_<second_id>").remove();
        }
        else if(data == "not"){
            $("#result_excluir_campo").empty().append("erro");
        }
        else {
            $("#result_excluir_campo").empty().append("sem acesso");
        }
    });
});
```

Or there is another way to accomplish the same result of the code above?

Comment: Use `class` and data-attribute.

Comment: You could also use the css selector `[id^=excluir_campo_]`.

Comment: I am trying use the class atribute, but how I could retrieve that value to store in a variable (like in the example I put in the question).

Comment: technically the id is still a single id, it just contains a space (which may or may not be valid). get the whole id and split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, never generate scripts in rendered html using any kind of loops. What if you have 1000 items? 1000 times your code, very inefficient.  You can use write a generic function and render that caller. This way, you save thousands of lines!
Secondly, NEVER use generated id's and id based functions, never ever! you can just use a generic class for that functionality, you do not need id selector. You just need an extra attribute like "key":

```
 <div class="my-functionality" data-key="15" />
    <div class="my-functionality" data-key="16" />
    <div class="my-functionality" data-key="17" />
    <div class="my-functionality" data-key="18" />
```

And you can just use either generated scripts in loops or [jquery's each selector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to bind events to your elements: you can wrap your click event like:

```
 $('.my-functionality').each(function(index, elem){
        $(elem).click(function(){
            //do you stuff here!
            var key = $(elem).data('key'); //this will read data-key attribute
        });

    });
```

Comment: ok, thanks by your sugestion. If I use this,  I can assume the value of 'index' will be value of 'data-key'? And I could use ${item_key} as  the value of 'data-key'?

Comment: No, as described here [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), index is the index of current element in your selector/array/anything else. thing jquery each as a for each loop. first argument corresponds the index variable, the second is the value itself. if you need a value or attribute, you must use $(elem), but if you need index, you can directly use it...